# How to work out a WooCommerce Recent Products Page that is sortable like other product pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Site is:

http://fretmill.com/

Page is:

http://fretmill.com/new-arrivals/

This is using the shortcode:

[recent_products per_page="-1" columns="3"]

Which was modified with a filter to limit the recent products to the last 15 days.

My site users would like to be able to filter the "new arrival" products by attributes similar to other product categories - by price, attributes, etc.

I'm not tied to the shortcode - I basically just need a page in my site that lists products added in the last 15 days which is sortable just like all of the other product pages. So a general product query limited to the last 15 days might work. I'm just not sure how to do that in WooCommerce, although as I'm typing it seems like it should be fairly simple - essentially just like a blog page listing the last 15 days of posts, but querying products instead? As long as it works with the various WooCommerce layered navigation widgets so users can sort by attributes etc.

Comment: The filter widgets only work on product archive pages.. Like shop or category archives

Comment: So, shouldn't there be some way that I could make a shop archive that shows all products posted in the last 15 days sorted by post date? Then the filter widgets would work, right?

Comment: Well you can already sort the shop page by date. I'm a little stuck on whether it is possible to have a second "shop" archive... which seems like your goal.

Comment: So - I'm thinking I could take the WooCommerce "archive" page, which is also the main shop page, and make a copy of it that works as a page template so that I can apply it to a page called "New Arrivals" - but when I did that, the page is blank - apparently there is no query going on.

Comment: I tried to run a new query for the Product post type, but that seems to hang up. Maybe someone could advise in how I could use the WooCommerce Archive as a custom page template?

Comment: I think the nutshell of what I need is: a WooCommerce archive page that displays products from all categories that were posted in the last 15 days, that I can apply as a page template to a specific page.